# Rails ActiveRecord joining issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have the following code: `subscribers = Subscriber.find(:all, :joins => :profile, :conditions => ['subscribers.active IS NULL'])`

When I do this: `puts subscribers.first.inspect`, I should be seeing the profile information as well, but I'm not... Here are the model associations

```
class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  has_many :medias
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :subscriber
end
```

I am still trying to get used to writing joins in MySQL so I apologize for the sloppiness

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
subscribers = Subscriber.find(:all, :include => :profile, :conditions => ['subscribers.active IS NULL'])
```

However inspect doesn't look into nested relations. You can try `to_yaml`:

```
puts subscribers.first.to_yaml
```

Result is structured and easy readable and `include` is used only for performance.
It fetches profile with subscriber in single query.
You can also do:

```
puts Subscriber.where('active IS NULL').includes(:profile).first.to_yaml
```

Generally you should use joins when you want to filter data by a joined relation column.

Comment: I tried that but it still is only pulling back the subscriber information without the profile information

Comment: I tried your modified suggestion and its still ONLY pulling back subscriber information. I had to do this `subscribers.first.profile.to_xml` before it would work, which results in a secondary query, which isn't what I am wanting :(